# Do redirect after redirecting options removed in .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I do some redirecting things on my apache server using rewrite rules and it worked well and after I removed this options, my browser get redirect link yet but when I test it in other system it does't.
This is so strange to me and I don't find out what is the problem.
Is there some logic explain for this or I dreaming?

I am using win 10 in client and apache-2.2 on server, if them help.

Tanks.

Comment: If this is intended to be a _temporary_ redirect, then make it a 302, as opposed to a 301 (ie. permanent). 301s are naturally cached locally, 302s should not be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser has cached the redirect, so it doesn't even make the request to the page. You need to clear the browser cache or wait for the cache to expire.

You established a HTTP 301 redirect, indicating that the page moved *permanently*. Use a HTTP 302 redirect for temporary redirects.